# Destructor running twice on class instance declared inside lambda capture specifier

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

When running the following code, it seems that the destructor is running twice. I have a theory that this might have to do with an automatic move constructor being added, but I'm not sure how to test this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Structure {
   Structure(int n) :
      Value(n) {
      std::cout << "constructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }
   ~Structure() {
      std::cout << "destructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }
   int Value;
};

int main() {
   int Init = 4;
   std::function<void()> Function = [Instance = Structure(Init)] () {
      std::cout << "Value is: " << Instance.Value << std::endl;
   };
   Function();
   Function();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor: 4
destructor: 4
Value is: 4
Value is: 4
destructor: 4
```

Is this output correct?

Comment: So when you made your own copy constructor and move constructor and put breakpoints in; which was hit?

Comment: And `operator=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I defined the move and copy constructors manually and also saw errors when I instructed the compiler to delete them in a variant of the code below. Everything seems normal.

Revised code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Structure {
   Structure(int n) :
      Value(n) {
      std::cout << "constructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }

   Structure(const Structure& other) :
      Value(other.Value) {
      std::cout << "copy constructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }

   Structure(Structure&& other) :
      Value(other.Value) {
      other.Value = -1;
      std::cout << "move constructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }

   ~Structure() {
      std::cout << "destructor: " << Value << std::endl;
   }
   int Value;
};

int main() {
   int Init = 4;
   std::function<void()> Function = [Instance = Structure(Init)] () {
      std::cout << "Value is: " << Instance.Value << std::endl;
   };
   Function();
   Function();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor: 4
move constructor: 4
destructor: -1
Value is: 4
Value is: 4
destructor: 4
```

Comment: This is the answer to "I have a theory that this might have to do with an automatic move constructor being added, but I'm not sure how to test this; any suggestions?." which I feel is a much better question than "am I right"?

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` works by copying the callable object you provide. There is no copy-elision here, since your lambda is not an `std::function` but of an anonymous, unrelated type.

Hence, the two destructors you see are:

- The `Instance` member of the original, temporary, lambda;
- The `Instance` member of the copy of the lambda that was stored into the `std::function` and lived until the end of `main`.